# AWT to SWING transition

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

public synchronized void start(){
    running=true;
    thread = new Thread(this,"Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    running=false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer=System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ns=1000000000.0/60.0;
    double delta=0;     
    requestFocus();
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta+=(now-lastTime)/ns;
        lastTime=now;
        while(delta>=1){
            update();               
            delta--;
        }
        render();           
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-timer>1000){
            timer+=1000;
            frame.setTitle(title+"  |  "+updates+" ups "+frames+" FPS");
            updates=0;
            frames=0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}


public void update(){       
}

public void render(){   
    BufferStrategy bs=getBufferStrategy();  
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();  
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    game.start();
}
}
```

I have this nice AWT based animation engine, which I use in my new 2D sprite game. I haven't developed it myself but took it from *CHERNO project* youtube series.

However, now when working on my own project I am starting to face problems with buttons and labels. I simply don't know how to add them. And yes I have read that mixing AWT and SWING is not recommended.

Thus, my dilemma would be what to do with buttons? Is there an easy way to transorm this to swing based animation engine keeping the game cycle methods: render(), update() and not loosing in performance (because I already had some bad SWING performance experience and I would say "YES, I can believe it is not butter/AWT").

Or maybe there is a way just to add those bloody buttons without facing big problems later in development due to AWT and SWING mixing?

Comment: Essentially, you can't (without a lot of problems), as you're using a active painting process (through the use of the `BufferStrategy`) which is incompatible with the passive painting process of Swing.  About the only thing you can do is have a "normal" view with your buttons/labels and what not and your "game" view using the `BufferStrategy`

Comment: *"Is there an easy way to transorm this to swing based animation engine keeping the game cycle methods"* - The only way you could do this is through the use of a Swing `Timer`, while it won't remove your `update` methods, your `render` methods would need to change, as you would need to supply the `Graphics` context to which the output would be rendered, this wouldn't be "that" hard, as at the end of the days, it's essentially all that either approach would really require.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean by 'normal' view? Just opening another window? Cause I do have choice of doing homecooking my own buttons through MouseListener and for more complex displays just opening new windows with Swing being implemented. Would that be compatible and work good?

Comment: Or a `JPanel`, so long as you weren't trying to control it's painting process.  Yes, you could also cook your own, that's up to you

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I understand you correctly with JPanel suggestion I just could add it on top of my animation?

Comment: No, not really, as you'd be mixing two different painting approaches.  You need to display one or the other, you won't be able to display both

Comment: @MadProgrammer what would be the best way to display text in this AWT environment? Cause homecooked buttons is one thing, but spriting fonts is too much :D